# body background color and div in image

Tags: html, css

I just wanna know if background is in color and content div is in image is possible?

```
<body style="background-color: black; ">
  <div id="header" style="background: url('xxx11.png') repeat left top;">

  </div>

  <div id="#container" style="background-image: url(xxx.png)">
  </div>
</body>
```

When I run, I can just see black color but cannot see the background image..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to note: You do not need `background-repeat:repeat;background-position:right top;` in the body's style.

Comment: @MatthewBaker, thanks.. i delete it but i can't see my background image yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="#container" style="background-url: url(xxx.png)">
```

should be

```
<div id="#container" style="background-image: url(xxx.png); width=500px; height=500px;">
```

Set the width and height to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You will see black color until you do not set width and height of the divs. You do not have set width or height of div or do not have content in it.That is why it is showing body's black  color. As you are using inline style so, you can use this:

```
<div id="header" style="background: url('xxx11.png') repeat left top; width:*px; height:*px;">
</div>

<div id="container" style="background-image: url(xxx.png); width:*px; height:*px;">
</div>
```

Comment: I already set but still seeing black.. i also forget to mention that my div is margin: 0 auto;

Comment: hey buddy you have to change * with numbers! did you?

Answer (score 1):

If your `<div>` is empty, it will be very small (1x1 pixel?), so you won't see your background.

So you can use CSS to set the size of your idv, so the background is shown. For example your *could* use:

```
#header {
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Note: the id of your container div is `#container`, I do not think that a `#` is allowed in a tag id...

Comment: Do I need to set position: absolute?

Comment: It is *a* solution to set the size of a block element (like a `<div>`), You could also create a `float` for example. It really depends on your requirements.

Comment: yeah if you want your two div to be SBS so, use `display:inline-block;`

Comment: my header div position is fixed and container is margin: 0 auto; is it any make difficult to see my background image ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
background: url(../img/pattern/59.png) 0 0 scroll #ccc;
```

```
<body style="background-color: black; ">
    <div id="header" style="background: url('img/4.png') repeat left top #CCC;height:200px;">

    </div>

    <div id="container" style="background-image: url(img/5.png);height:200px;"></div>
</body>
```

Above code is tested, body was all black screened because you did not defined height property for divs.